# Lagged variables as IVs

Tags: multiple-regression, panel-data, instrumental-variables, lags

I want to run a endogeneity check on a particular explanatory variable. My dependent variables has value added of services in manufacturing exports, while my suspected endogenous variable is overall manufacturing value added (MVA). As an IV for MVA, I decided upon its lagged value, i.e., MVA(t-1). However, while trying to run a 2SLS IV regression, Stata is dropping this lagged variable, and I'm consequently unable to test for endogeneity. Any suggestions on how to overcome this? The usage of lagged variables as IVs has a large literature. 
The dataset I'm using is a panel dataset, with more than 6000 observations.

Comment: Depending on whether you have more time periods than cross sections, I recommend looking into System GMM